# Can I use my iPad as a Virtual CD Deck

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, music, mediaplayer, itunes

Is there is an app for iPad that will emulate basic CD deck functionality using iTunes tracks? All the DJ software I've seen (or bought) seems to include mixer/deck/additional features I don't require (I have a vinyl-based DJ set-up and just need an additional player for music I only have digital copies of).

To clarify - I'm looking for a software version of something like [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000JFQ0RI). I just need basic cue/jog controls and a speed control.

Update: please see [this video](http://www.ehow.com/video_2373398_choose-cd-player-djing.html) for an overview of the sort of thing I'm looking for (NB. basic bpm adjustment and cueing controls is really all I need - hotstarts and looping would be great but I can live without them.)

Comment: What's wrong with the Music app set to shuffle by album or with DJ Mode?

Comment: What exactly is a CD deck?  Is that a equal to a multidisk changer?

Comment: See above. It's for a dj setup - I need an equivalent to dj turntables. with speed controls and jog/cue. It's for mixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me see if I understand your concerns. You want an app with a single deck interface that takes up the entire screen, but all the DJ apps out there all use a split-screen dual-deck interface with no single deck option. Is that right?

How about this? It's the only DJ app with a single deck interface I can find so far. Got cue points, loops, effect, the whole shebang.

**Mixmo-DJ/Pro**

Homepage: http://www.mixmodj.com/

App Store links:

- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mixmo-dj/id483351955
- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mixmo-dj-pro/id461366285

Youtube Videos:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGeyVmkmdTE
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvhHybAfJ9M

Here's a review from a trust source, **Digital DJ Tips**:

http://www.digitaldjtips.com/2011/12/review-mixmodj-for-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch/

**IK Multimedia's DJ Rig** also has a single deck interface but it's for iPhone, so it might not look great on iPad but it still does what you want..

- http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/djrigiphone/
- http://itunes.apple.com/app/dj-rig/id478831717
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3QhZuHbAUY

Comment: That looks pretty decent. Will give it a spin when I get home from work. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Traxpad has been my virtual turntable for two years. While not in active development it seems, it is absolutely the most multi-touch friendly and reliable single turntable app I've used. It's pricey, but I install it on two iPads and use it every week on the radio and in the club.

I've also used iRig in single-deck mode, blown up to iPad screen dimensions, and my only complaint is that the UI requires careful touching on tiny areas to bring up essential functions that should be exposed and easy to use full-time. The sound quality and price are great, but only Traxpad Gets It when it comes to replacing a Technics 1200.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! There is a really cool app called Tonetable which turns your ipad into a virtual cdj that you can plug straight into a mixer, provided you have the right connection etc, and use as if it was a cdj, or you can use it with apps like Serato. Check it out at http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tonetable/id322367764?mt=8 or google tonetable for videos of people using it.

Comment: Thanks for posting. But I'm not sure this does what I need - it looks like it is an interface that sends control signals to software like Serato, not an actual player.

I want an iPad app that outputs the audio itself and allows the pitch and bmp to be modified. A software version of a simple CD DJ deck.

Comment: This app allows you to adjust the pitch, allows you to scratch, rewind, loop, works like a basic cdj. Check out this video to see some of those features in action http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gbpgjU9yXY - it's in spanish but you'll get the idea when you see the guy adjusting the pitch.

Comment: I don't think so - it is controlling another piece of software which is outputting the audio. I want the iPad app to output the AUDIO itself without me having to buy Serato or whatever.

This http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tempo-magic-pro/id390593407?mt=8 is more like what i need.

Comment: No, I have the app myself, it outputs audio itself. Check this video which shows someone using it on an iphone by itself and adjusting the pitch http://youtu.be/cs1zi5tNCJI

Serato is just one way of interfacing the software with the rest of your equipment.

Comment: From the comments to that video:

Can i use it if i dont have an Audio interface? If yes, then how?
TimbaztiCc 2 years ago

No, you'll need to run it into some sort of audio input. For example, Scratch Live, Traktor Scratch, etc, all require you to have their own audio interfaces. You can use your computer's built-in audio input for some software, such as Deckadance, but it'll add a small amount of latency.

I don't want to have to buy this Deckadance software and I don't want *any* latency if I'm mixing it up live.

Comment: If you do not find anything, are you interested in working together to develop something? I'm an old dev, and even older acoustic blues player...

Comment: @DavidDelMonte - I haven't found anything. Would be happy to collaborate, drop me a note at 5arx@webdoma.in to discuss if you like :-)

Comment: I've sent you a test message....

Comment: I've replied :-)

Answer (score -1):

How about DJ for iPad,  it's not cd decks but its the same principle??